# MYSQL query for "row-subrows" ordering selection

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table, where `SUBROW` shows the ID of a row (if not 0), and indicates whether the row is a subrow of another row.

```
ID | SUBROW
1  | 0
2  | 0
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 1
```

I need a query, which would select in the following order:

```
ID | SUBROW
1  | 0
3  | 1
5  | 1
2  | 0
4  | 2
```

Ideas?

Comment: If a parent's id always less than the child's: `ORDER BY LEAST(ID,SUBROW), ID`. This will only work for two levels though.

Comment: Thanks. You may post your answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parent's id is always less than the childs, you could use something like: `ORDER BY LEAST(ID, SUBROW), ID` to order first by the parent's then the child's.

...actually, assuming only two "layers" (parents and children, no grandchildren), the parent id does not need to be less than the childs

`ORDER BY IF(SUBROW = 0, ID, SUBROW), SUBROW <> 0, ID`

or

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBROW = 0 THEN ID ELSE SUBROW END, SUBROW <> 0, ID`

This orders by the parent id (if there is one) first, then whether the row had a parent, and then the final `, ID` is only necessary if you want to guarantee the order of the children cannot not change from one execution of the query to the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tmp.Id,
tmp.SUBROW FROM (
SELECT d.Id,
d.SUBROW,
CASE WHEN d.SUBROW=0 THEN CAST(d.Id AS VARCHAR)+'00' 
ELSE
CAST(d.SUBROW AS VARCHAR)+ CAST(d.Id AS VARCHAR) +'0' 
 END lvl
FROM data d) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.lvl
```

Kind of tricky, but no need to use some `mysql` (ish) functions like `LEAST`